# Delete Attributed to Wrong User

Tags: bug, review-queues, low-quality-posts

In the LQP queue, there seems to be a bug where the penultimate review user is attributed the delete result, when it should be the last. See the screenshot below of [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11074020);

[image: LQP Bug Screenshot]

As you can see, I was attributed **Recommend Deletion** *1 min ago* and the post was deleted *1 min ago*, but the penultimate reviewer was given the **Delete** action, and the time for that was *1 hour ago*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are seeing it wrong.

Most reviewers in the LQRQ are sub-20K, or have exhausted their delete-votes.
Which is why they only "recommend deletion" instead of voting to "delete".

[20K users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) get a limited amount of votes for deleting negatively-scored answers.

The [revision-history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35085037/revisions) says:

> Post Deleted From Review

As does the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35085037/timeline):

[image]

Comment: To be a little clearer... the delete vote did nothing.

Comment: Or at least, nothing more than a "recommend delete". Which is the reason high-rep users try to use their delete-votes before reviewing the LQRQ.

Comment: You're right, it does count as recommend delete. At least that's something. (I was never sure about that.)

Comment: I can't see the revision-history or the timeline (I guess because I don't have enough rep to see deleted posts).

Comment: @worldofjr: Yes, sorry. Allowing everyone to see the timeline, always, was seems a bug: [There are no permission issues with the timeline](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273601/257849)